# Bootstrap - Split button in a justified button group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Does bootstrap 3 provide any way of adding a split button to a justified button group ?

Set up an example [here](http://jsbin.com/cohazubu/1/edit?html,output).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't fix all of the styling differences, but you can use display: table elements to wrap items you want to be 100% width  the fixed width item to sort of pad the area.

Here's an updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/cohazubu/8/edit

Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="padded-table">
  <div class="tc-fluid">
    content you want to be 100%
  </div>

  <div class="tc-fixed" style="width: 40px">
    content with a fixed width
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.padded-table {
  width: 100%; 
  display: table;
}

// Need to specify inline/mix in a width setting
.tc-fixed {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tc-fluid {
    display: table-cell; 
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```